# How import mdi font to vuetify with vue and vuetify cdn?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

How import mdi font to vutify? Below code does not working. I am using CDN.

```
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify


const vuetify = createVuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', //'mdiSvg', //  || 'mdiSvg' || 'md' || 'fa' || 'fa4' || 'faSvg'
  }
})

  createApp({
    delimiters: ['{-', '-}'],
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    }
  }).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

In html:

```
<v-btn icon="mdi-dots-vertical" v-bind="props"></v-btn>
<v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `index.html` between `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
```